# Change Date stamp to just Month and Year

Tags: windows, batch-file, date, timestamp

I found this simple code to copy my files and paste them into a new folder and label it with the current MMDDYYYY. I'm trying now to get it to just give me the month and year (Ex. March 2021).

```
@Echo Off
Set "sd=C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXX\Documents\Global S Programs"
Set "dd=I:\Quality\CMM Global S programs\Global S IBGC3 (CMM1) Programs"
Set "ds="
If Not Exist "%sd%\" Exit /B
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined ds Set "ds=%%A_%%B_%%C"
If Not Defined ds Exit /B
RoboCopy "%sd%" "%dd%\%ds%" /E
```

Comment: That's not simple code. It uses obscure trickery to get the date values. You need to use something like [How to echo month name using DOS CMD Catch file](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/tech-tips-tricks/how-to-echo-month-name-using-dos-cmd-catch-file/)

Comment: Thanks.        Being knew to coding how would I include that into the code?